# SP 2013 and IE 11

Tags: web-part, internet-explorer, design

I noticed that when I was trying to edit my web part in SP 2013, I could not. All of the choices under the web part tab were greyed out.  And the "up/down" icon in the web part did nothing. At least initially when it had no content (not sure if then running in compatibility mode might allow as I did later see that work - very flaky).  But I worked around this by using Chrome.  I currently have version 11.0.9600.16518 of IE

Pathetic that MS's own browser won't work!

Answer (score 1):

Install the SharePoint 2013 Service Pack 1.

Here you can find the complete list of bug fixes and improvements.

http://www.emanuelebartolesi.com/post/2014/02/28/Rilasciato-il-Service-Pack-1-di-SharePoint-2013

Comment: Thanks for answering your first question here on sp.se! Can you edit your post to include more information? Perhaps with information stating that this is fixed in the service pack with a link verifying that information rather than flat out saying install the SP with no further information.

Comment: I do see the following mentioned on the SP1 page "Improves compatibility with Internet Explorer 11".  link to SP1 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2817429

Comment: there's at least one thread on technet that indicates it's still broken after SP1 see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/74d5d0ae-a661-4f0c-8960-d25085f11bd5/sharepoint-2013-sp1-and-ie-11-still-broken-editing-publishing-pages?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Maybe you want to read this before apply SP1:
http://blog.imason.com/sharepoint-2013-sp1-breaks-search-and-edit-page-properties/

Answer (score 1):

As many of you may know, Microsoft just rolled back SP1 for SharePoint 2013! Besides, SP1 is not a trivial update and will likely require an entire rebuild of your SharePoint farm.

The much easier fix is to install the following hotfix: [KB 2600088](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088)

The issue is that the browser definition files for .NET 4 in conjunction with ASP.NET Forms are not up-to-date, and IE 11 is incorrectly detected as an unknown browser. SharePoint in turn treats it as a downlevel browser, thus stripping out a lot of functionality that would typically make use of more advanced javascript functions and the like.

The hotfix updates these browser definition files to correctly detect IE 11's user agent string, allowing SharePoint to function normally with this browser.

The best way to test this theory is to hit F12 and open your IE developer toolbar when viewing your SharePoint site. If you change your User Agent string to IE 10, the site should function normally. This highlights the issue that the hotfix remedies.

Answer (score 0):

worked around this by using Chrome.